# Cannot link up Hotmail account in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, hotmail

For a while now, I have had my Hotmail account hooked up to my Thunderbird, along with a couple of others. Recently however, it has had issue connecting. None of the other accounts have any issue (I have one with a hosting site, and another with google+).

I have since tried deleting and re-adding the account. However, it cannot connect, saying that there is an issue with the account details (username/password). I *know* this information is correct, as I have been to Hotmail.com and used the same details with no issue.

#### Incoming: POP3 (also tried IMAP)

- **Server Hostname:** imap-mail.outlook.com
- **Port:** I have tried (Default) 995; 110; and Autodetect
- **SSL:** I have tried SSL/TLS; STARTTLS; and AutoDetect
- **Authentication:** I have tried Normal Password; and AutoDetect

#### Outgoing: SMTP

- **Server Hostname:** smtp-mail.outlook.com
- **Port:** I have tried (Default) 587; and Autodetect
- **SSL:** I have tried SSL/TLS; STARTTLS; and AutoDetect
- **Authentication:** I have tried Normal Password; and AutoDetect

I have also gone and removed any saved passwords linked to the account (“Tools -> Options -> Saved Passwords -> Remove [Selected passwords]”)

All to no avail. **What is causing this, and how can I fix it?**

---

**Edit:** I have also found [this solution](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1002941) involving Hotmail's two-step verification; but it was not enabled on my account, and therefore not applicable to my case.

Comment: You wrote that you're using port 995.
Probably just a typo on your side,
but generally (and for my hotmail.com account) the default is port 993.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you're using port 995. Probably just a typo on your side, but generally (and for my hotmail.com account) the default is port 993. –

It's port 995

Comment: This post is pretty confusing.  What are readers supposed to do with this information to solve what was asked in the question?